# In Flex/Actionscript, How Can I Know WHICH LocalConnection.send Generated A Status Error?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

Consider The Following Actionscript/Flex code:

```
  var LC:LocalConnection=new LocalConnection();
  LC.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, Status);
  LC.send('A', 'SomeMethodName', 'Message');
  LC.send('B', 'SomeMethodName', 'Message');
  LC.send('C', 'SomeMethodName', 'Message');

public function Status(event:StatusEvent):void {
  if (event.level=='error') {
    // How Can I Know if the error came from 'A', 'B', or 'C' above?
  }
}
```

Assuming I do *NOT* want to run the sends in series, but in paralell (all at once), as above, and further assuming that one, and only one of the send commands will generate a status event where level='error':

How can I detect which send command produced the status error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i had to use multiple LocalConnections i'd used a different instance for every ConnectionID and created a holder class to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a status even will be raised for *every* message that you send.  So if you got 2 status messages before then error, then it's C.

You could have some wrapper around LocalConnection that stores messages that it sends in some array, and removes them every time a status message is received.  When you get an error the message at the head of the queue would be the one that errored out.

Comment: How can you be so sure that I will get the two status messages before the error message?  Say, for example that it errors on "B" - I don't think you can count on the sequence of events being status,error,status.  Couldn't it just as easily be status,status,error?  It could well take longer to determine error than success, in this asynchronous environment.  Even if I use the second idea, I still am faced with exactly how to associate a particular event response with the exact send which sent it.  Can you be more specific about how I might maintain that association relationship?